# wordpress custom meta not displaying

Tags: wordpress

I cant seem to get my custom meta (wp_alchemy) to display with the below. The rest is working fine, it displays the pages that use a custom template as it should.

```
<?php // Display list of pages using the template page-landing.php

    $product_pages_args = array(
        'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template',
        'meta_value' => 'page-landing.php',
        'depth' => -1,
        'hierarchical' => 0
    );

    $product_pages = get_pages( $product_pages_args );

    //$custom_metabox = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_custom_meta',TRUE); 

    echo '<table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Service name</td>
                    <td>Cost</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>';

        foreach ( $product_pages as $product_page ) {

            echo '
            <tr>
                <td>
                <a href="'.get_permalink($product_page->ID).'">'.$product_page->post_title .'</a>
                </td>
                <td>'; ?>
            <?php   
            $custom_metabox = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_custom_meta',TRUE);     
                    echo $custom_metabox['landing-para'];

                echo '</td>
            </tr>';
        }

     echo '</table>'; ?>
```

Comment: `$product_page->ID` != `$post->ID`, are you see the error? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `$product_page` as post data, then use `$product_page->ID` instead of `$post->ID`.

```
 $custom_metabox = get_post_meta($product_page->ID,'_custom_meta',TRUE);
```

Comment: I LOVE YOU! That had me pulling my hair out X